# How to Delete Drive That is Missing From a RAID

Tags: terminal, raid

I had a RAID drive fail. I replaced the bad drive with a new one and, after some work, got it up and running. I want to delete the bad drive from the config. This is the latest listing:

```
AppleRAID sets (1 found)
===============================================================================
Name:                 Data
Unique ID:            A14C84DA-C663-4FFB-95BB-8D102912A2E5
Type:                 Mirror
Status:               Degraded
Size:                 2.0 TB (2000054910976 Bytes)
Rebuild:              manual
Device Node:          disk5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DevNode   UUID                                  Status     Size
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  -none-    1BAC60DD-CA77-444D-B4C4-BDAB73248240  Missing/Damaged
1  disk4s2   9BB10E86-07CF-4F6A-8886-FCC3607E4729  Online     2000054910976
2  disk2s2   FC76DA2A-4FDD-4795-A3B6-D35770476FCF  Online     2000054910976
===============================================================================
```

I just noticed when pasting this, the status is still degraded. When I tried to remove it I got this error:

```
@ Yamadoshi (curt)| => sudo diskutil appleraid remove 1BAC60DD-CA77-444D-B4C4-BDAB73248240
Password:
Usage:  diskutil appleRAID remove MemberDeviceName|MemberUUID
    RAIDSetVolumePath|RAIDSetDeviceName|RAIDSetUUID
Remove a member or spare from an existing RAID set.
Ownership of the affected disks is required.
Example: diskutil AppleRAID remove disk2s4 /Volumes/RAID
     diskutil AppleRAID remove 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 disk5
```

How do I get rid of the missing drive? Do I have some other problem given the Degraded status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, that you have to add the path to the Mounted volume at the end instead of the disk number. For example:

```
diskutil AppleRAID remove 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 /Volumes/MYMOUNTEDDISK/
```

Comment: I no longer have a software RAID so I'm assuming this works.